# How to find an Unmanaged device through Android management API?

Tags: android, api, enterprise, android-management-api

I am using Android management API to control the device in my MDM project.I want to know whether any specific way available to find unmanaged devices in the enterprise or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to find deleted or disabled devices, you can use [devices.get](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/get) and check for the [DeviceState](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices#devicestate).